# Showing error message if input is not number

Tags: java, eclipse

I am having a problem on finding out how to show the "invalid input Good bye" message if someone for example inputs anything other than a number (e.g. "*" / "xyz") for the value of a,b,c in the quadratic calculator that I made

```
    DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("0.00#");
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    Double a,b,c;
    System.out.println("Welcome to the Grand Quadratic Calculator ! ");
    System.out.print("Enter value of a = ");
    a = sc.nextDouble();
    System.out.print("Enter value of b = ");
    b = sc.nextDouble();
    System.out.print("Enter value of c = ");
    c = sc.nextDouble();
    double xone = (-b + Math.sqrt(b * b - 4 * a * c)) / 2 * a;
    double xtwo = (-b - Math.sqrt(b * b - 4 * a * c)) / 2 * a;

        if(b * b - 4 * a * c >= 0)
        {
            System.out.println("x1 = " + df.format(xone));
            System.out.print("x2 = " + df.format(xtwo));
        }

        else
            System.out.print("Invalid Input. \nGood Bye.");
```

Comment: What do you mean? you want to print that if the input isn't a number?

Comment: use `hasNextDouble` with `if` along with `nextLine` inside `else` to flush the unwanted input

Answer (score 1):

When the user enters invalid input, `sc.nextDouble()` will throw `InputMismatchException`.
That will crash your current program,
the code printing the "Invalid Input" message will never be reached.

You can wrap your code in a `try` block, and catch this exception:

```
try {
    System.out.print("Enter value of a = ");
    a = sc.nextDouble();
    // ...
} catch (InputMismatchException e) {
    System.out.print("Invalid Input. \nGood Bye.");
    // return or exit with failure
}
```

The "Good Bye" message suggests you want to exit on invalid input.

If you don't actually want to exit, then you can wrap the user input part, and the try-catch block within a loop, with limited or unlimited retries.

Answer (score 0):

To guide against wrong input from the user, you should put both the input statements and all arithmetic operations into a try .... catch block.

Try the code below :

```
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("0.00#");
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

Double a,b,c;
System.out.println("Welcome to the Grand Quadratic Calculator ! ");
System.out.print("Enter value of a = ");

try { //this line will disallowing the program from terminating when the users inputs an invalid value

a = sc.nextDouble();
System.out.print("Enter value of b = ");
b = sc.nextDouble();
System.out.print("Enter value of c = ");
c = sc.nextDouble();
double xone = (-b + Math.sqrt(b * b - 4 * a * c)) / 2 * a;
double xtwo = (-b - Math.sqrt(b * b - 4 * a * c)) / 2 * a;

    if(b * b - 4 * a * c >= 0)
    {
        System.out.println("x1 = " + df.format(xone));
        System.out.print("x2 = " + df.format(xtwo));
    }
}
catch(InputMismatchException err){
    System.out.println("Invalid Input. \nGood Bye.");
}
```

The else statement have been removed and the catch block will handle all that.

I hope that worked.